# Asymptotically discrete ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, mg.metric-geometry, ultrafilters, independence-results

> **Definition 1.** A ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\omega$ is called *discrete* (resp. *nowhere dense*) if for any injective map $f:\omega\to \mathbb R$ there is a set $U\in\mathcal U$ whose image $f(U)$ is a discrete (resp. nowhere dense) subspace of the real line $\mathbb R$.

It is easy to see that each p-point is a discrete ultrafilter and each discrete ultrafilter is nowhere dense. By a [known result of Shelah](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.205.4087&rep=rep1&type=pdf), there are models of ZFC without nowhere dense ultrafilters.

I am interested in the ZFC-existence of asymptotic counterparts of discrete ultrafilters.

A subset $D$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is called *asymptotically discrete* if for any $r\in\mathbb N$ there exists a bounded set $B\subset X$ such that $d(x,y)\ge r$ for any distinct points $x,y\in D\setminus B$.

In particular, a subset $D$ of $\mathbb Z$ is asymptotically discrete iff for every $n\in\omega$ there exists a finite set $B\subset\mathbb Z$ such that $|x-y|\ge n$ for any distinct points $x,y\in D\setminus B$.

> **Definition 2.** A ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\omega$ is called *asymptotically discrete* if for every injective map $f:\omega\to\mathbb Z$ there exists a set $U\in\mathcal U$ whose image $f(U)$ is asymptotically discrete in the metric space $\mathbb Z$ endowed with the standard Euclidean metric.

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1336586239) Petrenko and Protasov proved that an ultrafilter on $\omega$ is asymptotically discrete if it is a $p$-point or a $q$-point. They also proved that under CH there are asymptotically discrete ultrafilters which are neither $p$-points nor $q$-points.

> **Problem 1.** Does an asymptotically discrete ultrafilter exist in ZFC?

**Remark 1.** If there exists a model of ZFC without asymptotically discrete ultrafilters, then in this model there is no $p$-points and no $q$-points. The existence of such a model is a well-known open problem in Set Theory. So, if  Problem 1 has a simple answer, then this answer is affirmative. Maybe Kunen's OK-ultrafilters are asymptotically discrete?

**Remark 2.** Any ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ containing the filter of subsets of Banach density 1 in $\omega$ is not asymptotically discrete (as every subset $U\in\mathcal U$ has non-zero Banach density).